# Argument of type char is incompatible with parameter type LPWSTR

Tags: c++, windows, pointers, user-interface, char

So I'm learning GUI in c++ to make windows stuff, under my WM_COMMAND case I have an if statement:

```
 //declared globally
 char textSaved[20];
 HWND TextBox;

 //within WM_COMMAND case
 if (LOWORD(wParam) == 4)
         {
             int gwtstat =0;
             //char *t = &textSaved[0];
             gwtstat = GetWindowText(TextBox, &textSaved[0], 20);
         }
```

and my compiler is telling me that the type "char" is incompatible with the parameter of type "LPWSTR". I'd appreciate it if someone told me what this means and how I could fix it. Also the point of this is to store the content of a text box.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374131(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Your program is compiled Unicode so you need to use WCHAR or wchar_t, not char.

Comment: @RaymondChen I tried that and it's still giving me the same error (just with WCHAR/whar_t instead of char)

Comment: @Ocean_ep Try `gwtstat = GetWindowText(TextBox,(LPWSTR)&textSaved, 20);`

Comment: @AnkitB Casting the pointer is the wrong thing to do here. It will fill a `char` buffer with `wchar_t`, which is both not meaningful and also will trigger a buffer overflow (and therefore a security flaw).

Comment: @RaymondChen Yes, I got that right after executing that statement on my machine I came to know my fault. and then answer this question on the basis on [visual Studio 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21250353/3110262)

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
std::vector<wchar_t> textSaved(20);
...
gwtstat = GetWindowText( TextBox, textSaved.data(), textSaved.size() );
testSaved.resize(gwtstat);
std::wstring str(textSaved.begin(), textSaved.end());
```

Comment: Um, that last line should be `std::wstring str(textSaved.begin(), gwtstate);` Otherwise you are capturing characters beyond those returned by `GetWindowText`.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are using `char[]` to get Window text.
and your application is in `UNICODE` configuration.
that`s why you are getting error as 'char is incompatible with LPWSTR'.

You can use two method as follows:

**METHOD 1** : 
About your current code:
As you are using `UNICODE` Char set for your application.

**`UNICODE` configuration of the application use  `<wchar.h>` file for string handling**

you can use following code:

```
wchar_t textSaved[20];
 HWND TextBox;

 //within WM_COMMAND case
 if (LOWORD(wParam) == 4)
         {
             int gwtstat =0;
             //char *t = &textSaved[0];
             gwtstat = GetWindowText(TextBox, &textSaved, 20);
         }
```

Or 
**Method 2:** 
If you are using `VS2010` or any `VS VERSION`.
Change project properties to [Multibyte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cwe8bzh0.aspx) so that your project can work with 'Multibyte' char like `Japanese char` support and you can use `char` datatype for any operation in the your application.

**As `MULTIBYTE` configuration of the application use the default `<string.h>` file for string handling**

Steps for setting to `multibyte`
**Go to project -> Properties-> configuration Properties->General -> Character Set**
and change char set to `MULTIBYTE`.

and you can use your code as:

```
   //declared globally
 char textSaved[20];
 HWND TextBox;

 //within WM_COMMAND case
 if (LOWORD(wParam) == 4)
         {
             int gwtstat =0;
             //char *t = &textSaved[0];
             gwtstat = GetWindowText(TextBox, &textSaved, 20);
         }
```

Hope this will help you to understand some thing.